# Read Specific Date File using AgeFileFilter

Tags: java, file, apache-commons-io, filefilter

How to Read specific date file Using AgeFileFilter? 
I declare particular date in property files. 
I tried to do that with

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new AgeFileFilter(cutoffDate, false);
```

It gives me Newer files

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new AgeFileFilter(cutoffDate, true);
```

And it gives me older with equal date files

But both of them not working as per my requirement then i also tried

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new AgeFileFilter(long cutoffDate);
```

But it gives me Older files with equal date files
And my requirement is to read or display only particular date file..
So how is it possible? 
Any help will be appreciate..Thank you in Advance

Comment: What does this line even mean  `FileFilter fileFilter = new AgeFileFilter(long cutoffDate);`? It is not valid Java, you cannot pass `long cutOffDate`.

Comment: @jbx https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter.html go through this ....and look out for AgeFileFilter(long cutoff) and its description

Comment: The description is clear. It will either give you files older than the specified cut off time, or newer than the specified cut off time. Not files exactly matching the cut off time. The `long` parameter is the timestamp in milliseconds, not just the date, so an exact match doesn't make sense. You can confirm it in the code: https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter.java

Answer (score 0):

`AgeFileFilter` only filters files before or after the cut off date-time instance.

Remember that the `cutOffDate` parameter is the unix date-time in milliseconds
Will you know the exact date and time by the millisecond and have it saved in your property file?

If yes (unlikely), why don't you simply write your own `FileFilter`? It is only a single method, and with Java 8 you can write it easily like this:

```
long cutOffDate = 1536584743813L;

FileFilter fileFilter = file -> file.lastModified() == cutOffDate;
```

I suspect that it is unlikely what you want though. Do you load just a date (without time) from your property file?

Then you probably want to get the date of the file from the last modified timestamp.

The following only accepts files that were modified today. Instead of `today` you can have any `LocalDate` loaded from your property file.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

FileFilter fileFilter = file -> LocalDate.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(file.lastModified())).isEqual(today);
```

Comment: yes in property file i only declare Date...Not time

Comment: So parse the date in whatever format you have in your property file, to get a `LocalDate` instance and use the second example I gave you.